# Postgres constraint for a subset of rows

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I have a Postgres table containing tasks (`tasks`). A task can link to many entities using a link table (`links`). Tasks can be one of many types.

A subset of tasks, denoted by their types (let's call it `S`) can only link to one entity. That is, in `link`, there can be exactly one record with that task's ID/primary key.

Is there a way to encode that into Postgres constraints so that's managed automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this using triggers:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unique_link() RETURNS trigger AS $unique_link$
    DECLARE
        t_type text;
        link_ct int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT task_type INTO STRICT t_type FROM tasks WHERE id = NEW.task_id;
        IF t_type = 'S' THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO STRICT link_ct FROM links
                WHERE task_id = NEW.task_id
            IF link_ct > 0 THEN
                 RAISE EXCEPTION '% of type % already has a link associated', NEW.task_id, t_type;
            END IF;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$unique_link$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER unique_link BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON links
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unique_link();
```